# SVN is unable to automerge two CSV files differing in just one line

Tags: csv, svn

We have language strings saved as CSV files in our application. Anyone from the developer team can edit the CSV files using our custom editor and then commit it to our SVN repository. 
Suppose developer A has this content in his local version:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
zzz
```

where `zzz` is his local change. Developer B commits his CSV file with this content:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

where `ddd` is his local change. Now when developer A updates from SVN, he gets a conflict, which SVN is unable to auto-resolve. The expected result should be either

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
zzz
```

or

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
zzz
ddd
```

It auto-resolves these things just fine in our .cs files. Is there a possibility to globally tell our SVN repository how to auto-resolve this kind of conflicts?